# Remove first 3 letters from column

Tags: mysql

Remove first 3 letters from column Year.

```
Table name = Register
Column name = Year
```

Sample:

```
Year
12/2014
05/1995
```

Solution would be:

```
2014
1995
```

How to make it ? Currently my code is:

```
SELECT * FROM Register WHERE Year...
```

Comment: What datatype is year?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `substr()`:

```
select substr(year, 4)
```

However, I might be inclined to use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(year, '/', -1)
```

Note:  In both these cases, the returned value is a string.  If you want this to be a number, you can include `+ 0`.